# Expo DateTimePickers cancel & ok button can't see at spinner display

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using expo DateTimePicker, My issue is when I choose spinner display their cancel and Ok buttons are not display but I can see on other display mode.

I used

"expo": "~43.0.2",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.5.2",

## My Code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Button, Platform} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

const App = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(1598051730000));
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    setDate(currentDate);
  };

  const showMode = (currentMode) => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };

  const showDatepicker = () => {
    showMode('date');
  };

  const showTimepicker = () => {
    showMode('time');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Button onPress={showDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
      </View>
      {show && (
        <DateTimePicker
          testID="dateTimePicker"
          value={date}
          mode={date}
          // is24Hour={true}
          display="spinner"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Comment: @Jumper | No, I couldn't. So, I just change to flutter!!!

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to be still unresolved for expo built apps,however for me at least,the problem appears only when testing the app in expo go app,after i built the app to be published in the stores,its working fine there.

[image]

Comment: That's correct, it is not visible while developing using EXPO, after build buttons are visible by default.